# Phylogenetic model using multiple entries for each species

Tags: mixed-models, phylogeny

I am relatively new to phylogenetic regression models. In the past I used PGLS when I had only 1 entry for each species in my tree. Now I have a dataset with thousands of records for a total of 9 species and I would like to run a phylogenetic model. I  read the tutorial of the most common packages (e.g. caper) but I am unsure how to build the model.

When I try to create the object for caper, i.e. using:

```
obj <- comparative.data(phy = Tree, data = Data, names.col = species, vcv = TRUE, na.omit = FALSE, warn.dropped = TRUE)
```

I get the message:

> Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
>     duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘Species1’, ‘Species2’, ‘Species3’, ‘Species4’, ‘Species5’, ‘Species6’, ‘Species7’, ‘Species8’, ‘Species9’

I understood that I may solve this by applying a MCMCglmm model but I am unfamiliar with Bayesian models.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5):

This is indeed not going to work with a simple PGLS from `caper` because it cannot deal with individuals as a random effect. I suggest you use `MCMCglmm` that is not much more complex to understand and will allow you to have individuals as a random effect. You can find excellent documentation from the package's author [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCglmm/vignettes/Overview.pdf) or [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCglmm/vignettes/CourseNotes.pdf) or an alternative documentation that's more dealing with some specific aspects of the package (namely tree uncertainty) [here](https://github.com/TGuillerme/mulTree/blob/master/doc/Vanilla_flavoured_phylogenetic_analyses.Rmd).

Really briefly to get you going:

```
## Your comparative data
comp_data <- comparative.data(phy = my_tree, data =my_data,
      names.col = species, vcv = TRUE)
```

Note that you can have a specimen column that can look like this:

```
   taxa        var1 var2 specimen
1     A  0.08730689    a    spec1
2     B  0.47092692    a    spec1
3     C -0.26302706    b    spec1
4     D  0.95807782    b    spec1
5     E  2.71590217    b    spec1
6     A -0.40752058    a    spec2
7     B -1.37192856    a    spec2
8     C  0.30634567    b    spec2
9     D -0.49828379    b    spec2
10    E  1.42722363    b    spec2
```

You can then set up your formula (similar to a simple `lm` formula):

```
## Your formula
my_formula <- variable1 ~ variable2
```

And your MCMC settings:

```
## Setting the prior list (see the MCMCglmm course notes for details)
prior <- list(R = list(V=1, nu=0.002),
              G = list(G1 = list(V=1, nu=0.002)))

## Setting the MCMC parameters
## Number of interactions
nitt <- 12000

## Length of burnin
burnin <- 2000

## Amount of thinning
thin <- 5
```

And you should then be able to run a default `MCMCglmm`:

```
## Extracting the comparative data
mcmc_data <- comp_data$data

## As MCMCglmm requires a column named animal for it to identify it as a phylo
## model we include an extra column with the species names in it.
mcmc_data <- cbind(animal = rownames(mcmc_data), mcmc_data)
mcmc_tree <- comp_data$phy

## The MCMCglmmm
mod_mcmc <- MCMCglmm(fixed = my_formula, 
                     random = ~ animal + specimen, 
                     family = "gaussian",
                     pedigree = mcmc_tree, 
                     data = mcmc_data,
                     nitt = nitt,
                     burnin = burnin,
                     thin = thin,
                     prior = prior)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will give it a go and let you know whether I can handle it or not.

Comment: What is the gain of specifying individuals as a random factor? My understanding is that all it does is accounting for overdispersion (as we would do in a generalised mixed effect model, as suggested by Zuur et al. in one of their books). Am I correct? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a function (perhaps in `MCMCglmm`) that allows to "assemble" the comparative data when multiple observations per species are present? In the code suggested by @thomas-guillerme `comp_data` is still created using `comparative.data` from `caper`, which gives the error described by @marco-gamba . Cheers

Comment: You could use the function `as.mulTree` from the [`mulTree`](https://github.com/TGuillerme/mulTree) package which creates objects that deal with multiple specimens and can be passed to `MCMCglmm` via `mulTree`. See the `mulTree` documentation example for more details.